# How do I restart windows services if it is crashes because of internet outage

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a Windows service that exits or crashed because of internet outage. Is there a simple way to monitor it to make sure it gets restarted automatically if it crashes?

**Update**

Here is the exception that we often got from the service.

```
An error has occured with the myservice:

Exception Message: The operation has timed out

Inner Exception: 

Date Time: 11/13/2015 8:03:09 PM

Stack Trace:    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at myservice.CrmSdk.CrmService.Delete(String entityName, Guid id)
   at myservice.myservice.timer1_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```

Here is what going on into the service.

```
public partial class myservice : ServiceBase
{
    public myservice()        {
        InitializeComponent();            
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("myservice Source"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource("myservice Source", "myservice Log");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "myservice Source";
        eventLog1.Log = "myservice Log";
    }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("myservice service started on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        //timer1.Interval = 60000;
        //timer1.Start();

        string ProcessHour = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"];
        int intProcessHour = Convert.ToInt32(ProcessHour);
        DateTime dtNow = DateTime.Now;
        if (dtNow.Hour < intProcessHour){
            DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
            System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
        }else{
            DateTime dtToday = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime dtStartDateTime = dtToday.AddDays(1).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));  
            System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
            timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
            timer1.Start();
            }
    }
    protected override void OnStop(){
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("myservice service stopped on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    public string GetParentAccountID(string strAgentID)
        {
            /* some logic to bring parentAccount
            */
        }

        public int GetAuditGrade(string strAuditGrade)
        {
            /* some logic to get grades of audits
            */           
        }

        public string GetAuditID(string sAgentID, string sDate)
        {
            /* some logic to get audit id
            */
        }

        public bool AuditRecordExists(string strAgentID, DateTime DateAuditStartDate)
        {
            /* some logic to check if audit record already exists
            */
        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                timer1.Stop();

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("myservice timer1_Elapsed begin on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                /* Create audit if not exists*/

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("myservice - Exception Notice.\n\n" +
                 "Exception Message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                 "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "\n\n" +
                 "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);

                eventLog1.WriteEntry("Exception. myservice timer1_Elapsed ended on " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

                string ProcessHour = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"];
                DateTime dtStartDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(ProcessHour));
                System.TimeSpan diff = dtStartDateTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
                timer1.Interval = diff.TotalMilliseconds;
                timer1.Start();

                MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorSender"],
                                   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorRecepient"],
                                   "myservice - Exception Notice",
                                   "An error has occured with the myservice:\n\n" +
                                   "Exception Message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                                   "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "\n\n" +
                                   "Date Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n\n" +
                                   "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPClient"]);
                client.Send(message);
            }
        }

        private void eventLog1_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: To fix service is not an option?

Comment: this could also be an option. but I don't have information on it

Comment: If so, I'd recommend you to start from recovery options (see service properties in "Services" snap-in), and fixing service.

Comment: You can configure a Windows Service to restart if it crashes. You can specify how many times it shall restart and you can specify a time offset to wait before restarting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the source code of the service, you should try to fix the service by adding proper error handling etc. If you do not have access to the source, you may try this.

1) Go to services

2) Right click on the service

3) Goto recovery tab

4) Select "Restart service" for first failure, 2nd failure and subsequent failures. Then click apply/ok.

Comment: can you please let me know If I would add proper error handling

Comment: Please share the source code of the windows service (if you have it). We may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: sorry for delay. I've edited the question with a code and the exception as well.

Comment: There are quite a few issues in your code. Use the code in my answer and re-write your service. It's better to move all methods that you call inside the "Process()" method to separate disposable class/classes.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like this;

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Timers;


namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class myservice : ServiceBase
    {
        private EventLog _eventLog1;
        private Timer _timer1;

        public myservice()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitialiseService()
        {
            try
            {
                const string source = "myservice Source";
                const string name = "myservice Log";

                _eventLog1 = new EventLog();
                if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source))
                {
                    EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, name);
                }

                _eventLog1.Source = source;
                _eventLog1.Log = name;

                WriteLog("myservice service started on " + DateTime.Now);

                int intProcessHour;
                string processHour = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProcessHour"];

                var interval = (int.TryParse(processHour, out intProcessHour) && intProcessHour > 0 &&
                                  intProcessHour < 24
                                ? intProcessHour
                                : 1) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                _timer1 = new Timer(interval);
                _timer1.Elapsed +=timer1_Elapsed;
                _timer1.Start();                    

               // Process(); //enable this if you want to process immidiately. Else the timer will process when it elapsed.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void Process()
        {
            try
            {
                GetParentAccountID("xxx");
                GetAuditGrade("yyyy");
                GetAuditID("tttt", "45354345");
                AuditRecordExists("rrrr", DateTime.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog(ex.Message);
                SendEmail(ex);
            }
        }

        private string GetParentAccountID(string strAgentID)
        {
            /* some logic to bring parentAccount
            */
        }

        private int GetAuditGrade(string strAuditGrade)
        {
            /* some logic to get grades of audits
            */
        }

        private string GetAuditID(string sAgentID, string sDate)
        {
            /* some logic to get audit id
            */
        }

        private bool AuditRecordExists(string strAgentID, DateTime DateAuditStartDate)
        {
            /* some logic to check if audit record already exists
            */
        }

        private void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                WriteLog("myservice timer1_Elapsed started at " + DateTime.Now);
                Process();
                WriteLog("myservice timer1_Elapsed finished at " + DateTime.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SendEmail(Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPClient"]))
                {
                    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorSender"],
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ErrorRecepient"],
                        "myservice - Exception Notice",
                        "An error has occured with the myservice:\n\n" +
                        "Exception Message: " + ex.Message + "\n\n" +
                        "Inner Exception: " + ex.InnerException + "\n\n" +
                        "Date Time: " + DateTime.Now + "\n\n" +
                        "Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace))
                    {
                        client.Send(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }


        private void WriteLog(string logEntry)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(logEntry) && _eventLog1 != null)
                    _eventLog1.WriteEntry(logEntry);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                InitialiseService();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }



        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            try
            {
                _timer1.Stop();
                _timer1.Elapsed -= timer1_Elapsed;
                WriteLog("myservice service stopped on " + DateTime.Now);
                _eventLog1.Close();
                _eventLog1.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```